# Moving line timegraph with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using d3.js to create a graph showing data, which is periodically updated (one time per second) in a line graph. The x axis (time) and the whole graph is continuously translated to the left.

I tried to base it on this tutorial: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/path/

This jsfiddle is what I got so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/panbert/dmynvjzx/

It works. But in the update method (last Method in the Javascript part)

```
//move the graph left
svg.selectAll(".line")
  .attr("d", line(data))
  .attr("transform", null)
  .transition()
  .duration(950)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x(0) - x(1000)) + ")");
```

I use a duration of 950 milliseconds for the transition which translates the graph 1 second to the left. In the tutorial the delay for the transition is 1 second, which makes more sense to me. Every second the graph is moved 1 second left by a translation which duration should take one second. That sounds more logical than a translation which takes 950 milliseconds.

If I increase the translations duration in the jsfiddle to 1 second in line 161 (like in the tutorial) i get graphical errors and it doesn't work as supposed anymore.

Can anyone explain to me, why that is?

Comment: What is your expectation? I run your fiddle and see that it works with the duration of 1s.

Comment: The fiddle runs with a duration of 950 ms.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are calling the update function after every 1 second

```
setInterval(update, 1000);
```

And the duration for transition is given

```
svg.selectAll(".line")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("transform", null)
      .transition()
      .duration(950)//this means that the transition will take 950 mili secs which is less than the update rate.
```

But when you do duration 1 sec exactly as update it will not give you the jump effect coz the transition did not get over, and you are updating the path with new values.

```
svg.selectAll(".line")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("transform", null)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)//this means that the transition will take 1000
```

So the best way would be, when you give duration 1000(1sec)
give update rate a little more than 1 sec say (1.1sec)

```
setInterval(update, 1100);
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/1apL7jwf/1/)

Hope this helps!